# Prove that there is no $n\in\mathbb Z$ s.t. $n+n=1$.

Tags: group-theory

Consider the group $(\mathbb Z,+)$. I want to prove that there is no $n\in \mathbb Z$ s.t. $$n+n=1.$$

Of course it's an obvious question if we consider the ring $(\mathbb Z,+,\cdot )$ since if $n+n=1$ then $2n=1$, then $n$ is a unit. But units are $1$ and $-1$, but neither $n=1$ nor $n=-1$ solve $2n=1$. So there is not solution.

---

How can I solve this question in the group $(\mathbb Z,+)$ ? What I tried is : suppose there is $n\in\mathbb Z$ s.t. $n+n=1$. Then 
$n=1-n$. But I don't see how to get a contradiction. I tried something as $$n+n=1\implies n+(1-n)=1$$
and thus $1=1$, so no contradiction.

Any idea ?

Comment: What is your definition of the group $(\Bbb Z,+)$? In other words, how is your set of integers defined, and in particular, how is your operation of addition defined? And what is $1$?

Comment: To complement the suggestion of @Arthur, I'll add that a proper answer to this question will vary wildly depending on which definition of $(\mathbb Z,+)$ you are using, making it pretty hard for us to answer your question satisfactorily except by wildly guessing.

Comment: If you assume that $n=1-n$, what you need to show is that $n\notin \mathbb Z$

Comment: Your question might makes more sense if you provide a characteristic property of element $1$. E.g. that $1$ is an element that generates the group.

Comment: @OscarLanzi: Does "even" or "odd" really makes sense in a group since euclidian division is not defined.

Comment: @John Yes, it does make sense, using multiplication rather than division. The even numbers are the elements of the subgroup generated by $2$.

Comment: @Arthur: I'm not really sure to understand the question. $\mathbb Z$ is the set of integer numbers (i.e. $\{...,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,...\}$.) But I can imagine that it's not really what you want to point out right ?

Comment: @John Yeah, the exact nature of the elements isn't that important. The exact meanings of $+$ and of $1$, however, are. Is it defined as an infinite cyclic group with $1$ as a generator (sounds dangerously circular to me)? Or have you defined the natural numbers and addition through the Peano axioms (with $1$ being the successor of $0$), and defined the integers as equivalence classes of pairs of natural numbers? Or something else?

Comment: One possibility is to take $\mathbb Z$ to be an infinite group which is generated by a single element, and take $1$ to be that element. As a side remark, one can prove that all such groups are isomorphic to each other: each is a "free group of rank 1". So this does truly capture $(\mathbb Z,+)$ in the abstract. I have doubts that this is your intent, though.

Comment: It is unclear what is meant by the element $1$ - since you regard $\mathbb Z$ as a group under addition, you can't identify it as a multiplicative unit. It is one of the generators of $\mathbb Z$ as a group - is that the role it is playing here?

Answer (score 2):

Let $G = (\mathbb{Z}, +)$.  Note that $G$ is an infinite abelian group generated by $1$.  (We use this characterization of $1$ when we say that the sum of $k$ copies of this $1$ gives the copy of $k$ in $G$.)  We will want to distinguish members of $G$ and members of the totally ordered ring $\mathbb{Z}$, generated by $1$, that are the sum of the same number of copies of the generator in each, which we will do by subscripting by either $G$, or $\mathbb{Z}$, respectively.

For the sake of contradiction, assume 
$$  n_G + n_G = 1_G  \text{.}  $$
Add $n_\mathbb{Z}$ copies of this equation to obtain
$$  n_\mathbb{Z}(n_G + n_G) = n_\mathbb{Z} 1_G  \text{.}  $$
(Here we are using the usual convention that $zg$ where $z \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $g \in G$ means the addition of $z$ copies of $g$.)  Notice that $n_\mathbb{Z}(n_G + n_G) = (2n)_\mathbb{Z}n_G$ and  $n_\mathbb{Z} 1_G = n_G$.  So we have
$$  (2n)_\mathbb{Z} n_G = n_G  \text{.}  $$
Cancelling in $G$, 
$$  (2n-1)_\mathbb{Z} n_G = 0_G  \text{.}  $$
This gives three possibilities.

- $n_G = 0_G$, making our assumption $0_G + 0_G = 1_G$, an impossibility,
- $G$ has a non-$0_G$ element of finite order, but $G$ has no torsion, or
- $(2n-1)_\mathbb{Z} = 0_\mathbb{Z}$, an impossibility (since the intersection of the odd integers and the even integers is empty).

Therefore, there is no $n_G$ such that $n_G + n_G = 1_G$.

Answer (score 0):

If $n+n=1$ then $n$ is a [generator](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GroupGenerators.html) of $(\mathbb{Z}, +)$, since $1$ itself is a generator and $1=2n$ is generated by $n$. Thus

either $n=1$ and $1=2$, I think this is only possible in the trivial group

or $n=-1$ and $-2=1$, like in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, for example

Comment: I don't find this convincing, because you have used the fact that the only generators of ${\mathbb Z}$ are $1$ and $-1$, which ios no easier to prove than the result itself!

Comment: @DerekHolt Let $m \in \mathbb{Z}$. The subgroup generated by $m$ is the set of multiples of $m$

Comment: Yes but how does that help?

Comment: The set of multiples of $m$ is $\mathbb{Z}$ if and only if $m$ is either $1$ or $-1$

Comment: But that statement is equivalent to the original question. You are going round in circles.

Comment: @DerekHolt At some point we will have to make an assumption that some statement is known to be true. Otherwise Mathmatics itself is just circular reasoning

Answer (score 0):

$\mathbb Z:=\left<1\right>$. We have that $2\mathbb Z=\left<2\right>$. Suppose there is $n\in\mathbb Z$ s.t. $2n=1$. This implies that $\mathbb Z\subset 2\mathbb Z$, and thus $\mathbb Z=2\mathbb Z$. Contradiction.

Comment: nice answer (and simple)